# Run GitlabCI goals without recompiling at every stage

Tags: java, maven, gitlab-ci

I have a modular Java project hosted on Gitlab, with some Gitlab CI to check the code everytime we push some changes. The problem is that the project grew quite a lot recently, and every CI pipeline now takes about 15 minutes to complete.

What I noticed is that the code is basically compiled three times: during the "build" job (which runs `mvn compile`), during the "test" job (which runs `mvn test`) ans during the "deploy" job (which runs `mvn install`). Also, the tests were run twice, once in "test" and once in "deploy".

I tried to change this behavior by transforming the `mvn test` into `mvn resources:testResources compiler:testCompile surefire:test` and `mvn install` into `mvn jar:jar install`, but now the tests fail because of unknown classes and packages (even if it does work when I try to run all the commands one after another manually), like `package my.project.package does not exist`.

Maybe am I trying to do something that Gitlab CI can't do ? Maybe there is a better way to do it ?

Here is my YAML file:

```
image: myproject:latest

variables:
  MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 -Dmaven.repo.local=$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.m2/repository -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.cli.transfer.Slf4jMavenTransferListener=WARN -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.showDateTime=true -Djava.awt.headless=true"
  MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "--batch-mode --errors --fail-at-end --show-version -DinstallAtEnd=true -DdeployAtEnd=true -U"

cache:
  key: new_cache
  paths:
    - .m2/repository/
    - target/

build:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - shell
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS clean compile

test:
  stage: test
  tags:
    - shell
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS resources:testResources compiler:testCompile surefire:test


install:
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - shell
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS jar:jar install:install
  only:
    - master
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently the default behavior of Gitlab CI is to delete the result of a job after it has been completed, but there are two features called `artifacts` and `dependencies` which allow a user to save some of the data and transmit it to other jobs. Now, the file looks like this:

```
image: myproject:latest

variables:
  MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 -Dmaven.repo.local=$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.m2/repository -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.cli.transfer.Slf4jMavenTransferListener=WARN -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.showDateTime=true -Djava.awt.headless=true"
  MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "--batch-mode --errors --fail-at-end --show-version -DinstallAtEnd=true -DdeployAtEnd=true -U"

cache:
  key: new_cache
  paths:
    - .m2/repository/
    - frontend/node_modules/

build:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - shell
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS clean compile
  artifacts:
    paths: 
      - backend/target/

test:
  stage: test
  tags:
    - shell
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS resources:testResources compiler:testCompile surefire:test
  dependencies:
    - build

install:
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - shell
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS jar:jar install:install
  dependencies: 
    - build
  only:
    - master
```

Now, the `test` and `deploy` jobs have access to the `target` directory and can run without recompiling everything. Combined with the caching of node_modules, it reduced the execution time to just 5 minutes.

Comment: The easiest, most robust and most widely used method is to **not** split the Maven build into steps.

Comment: This answer is simply not correct. Gitlab will clone the repo for each job, thereby resetting the timestamps of the source files. Artifacts however are zipped and unzipped, and retain their original timestamps. In subsequent jobs, Gitlab will then always recompile because the classes are older than the source files. See https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/234078.

Comment: Also, there's no need to explicitly define dependencies in each subsequent job. Subsequent jobs by default get all the artifacts from previous jobs. Use dependencies to prevent or limit artifacts being made available to a job.

Answer (score -1):

The best approach is not to split the Maven build into parts, but just run

`mvn clean install`

or

`mvn clean deploy`

without running the compile and test phases separately before.

Comment: The whole point of CI is to understand what steps went wrong. So getting a notification that build failed is rather ambiguous. That is why it's a must to separate build into steps and transfer artifacts between steps

Comment: @Shmarkus I agree that it would be better to separate, but this is not how Maven is designed.  You can try to work around this and separate the parts anyway, but this will mean that you probably run some parts of the build more than once.